# EXTJS4.1 : TreePanel and Cell Editing (Unexpected behavior of Cell Editing plugin)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a Tree Panel with two columns "Tree" and "Description".

I render tree and Description column from a TreeStore, The Description column is made editable using CellEditing plugin.

When i edit any cell under Description column, its corresponding Tree node's name changes to that of first tree node's name.

Here is my code,

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
        autoLoad : false,
        autoSync : true,

        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'data/tree.json',


        },

        fields: [
            {name: 'optionName',     type: 'string'}, {name: 'description', type: 'string'}
        ] 

    }
);

Ext.override(Ext.data.AbstractStore,{
    indexOf: Ext.emptyFn
}); 

Ext.define('AEV.view.TreePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

    title: 'Simple Tree',

    width: 700,
    height: 400,

    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    disableSelection:true,

    viewConfig : {
        emptyText : '<center><span class="empty-table">No data!</span></center>',
        singleSelect : true,
        stripeRows : true
    },

    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit:1
            })
    ],

    columns:[
        {
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            text: 'Tree',
            dataIndex: 'optionName',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: false
        },
        {
            text: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description',
            flex: 2,
            sortable: false,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: true
            }
        }   
    ],

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()

});
```

My tree.json is

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "optionName": "ABC",
            "expanded": true,
            checked: true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "optionName": "DEF",
                    checked: true,
                    "leaf": true, 
            "description" : ""
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "GHI",
                    checked: true,
                    "leaf": true, 
            "description" : ""
                }
            ], "description" : ""
        },
        {
            "optionName": "JKL",
            "expanded": true,
        checked: true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "optionName": "MNO",
                    checked: true,
                    "leaf": true, 
            "description" : ""
                }
            ], 
        "description" : ""
        },
        {
            "optionName": "PQR",
            checked: true,
            "expanded": true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "optionName": "STU",
                    checked: true,
                    "expanded": true,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "optionName": "VW",
                            checked: true,
                            "leaf": true, 
                "description" : ""
                        },
                        {
                            "optionName": "XYZ",
                            checked: true,
                            "leaf": true, 
                "description" : ""
                        }
                    ], 
            "description" : ""
                }
            ], 
        "description" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also overridden AbstractStore's indexOf config, which i saw as bug in http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131602-4.0.0-Cellediting-on-TreeGrid

I don't want the tree node names to change, as i edit any other column data. 
Help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I observed that each time i edit any cell under "Description" column(which is editable), the corresponding treecolumn gets loaded with the entire tree again, It in fact reloads the tree.json.

Comment: Ohhh... Finally i found the problem. It is the autoSync variable of store. It must be false otherwise each time you edit the cell, a request is made to the store to sync.